# javafx.Image на Android

Tags: java, android, javafx

Есть интерфейс, который надо имлементировать в проекте, однако он имеет объект `Image`, принадлежащий `javafx`. Как я могу конвертировать этот объект в `ImageView` или любой другой проект, который можно было бы использовать в проекте? Или, если это невозможно, как я могу использовать этот объект в коде, чтобы получить изображение? А также какие зависимости необходимо добавить в `.gradle`, чтобы `javafx` заработала на `android`?

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    public interface User
    {
        String getUserName();
        int getUId();
        Image getIcon();
    }
```

Comment: вряд ли это вам вообще нужно. замените его на ImageView

Comment: Проще  (и правильнее) сделать новый интерфейс

Comment: Насколько я знаю javafx не работает на андроид в принципе. Платформа не та. Хотя если есть желание можете написать свой фреймворк :)

Comment: @iamthevoid нет ни желания, ни во возможности, но это мне прислали в тестовом задании на Android-разрабочика. Я первый раз в жизни видел, чтобы в Android использовали FX. Хотя на мировом stackoverflow сказали, что это возможно (но запарно)

Comment: Тогда надо смотреть уже конкретно. Если можно проигнорировать этот метод, лучше возбуждать там исключение, если нельзя, то надо искать варианты. Может можно вытащить drawingCache и использовать его как битмап в imageView, и другие параметры просетить из Image в ImageView. Паттерн адаптер или как там оно называется. Насчет зависимостей ничего не скажу, у меня когда то несколько лет назад были проблемы с этим и больше я туда не суюсь :)